# Jest + Supertest: mocking data in request object in middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, supertest

I have tried a couple of approaches for the current problem I am working on using `jest.mock(...)` and `jest.spyOn(...)` but have been unsuccessful so far.

Let me provide some context to what I have so far

In my **contorller.ts**, I am making a post call to get back a decision

```
.....
.....
this.router.post('/decision', decisionMiddleware, this.finalDecision)
.....
.....

private finalDecision(){
 const finalDecision = req.decision;
 // do something further with the decision here
}
```

In my middleware `decisionMiddleware.ts`, I make a fetch call and populate the request object with the response from the fetch

```
async decisionMiddleware(req, res, next){
   ....
   ....
   const decisionRes = await fetch(url, req.body);
   req.decision = decisionRes; // I want to mock the data that gets populated here
   next()
   ......
   ......
}
export default decisionMiddleware;
```

In my test file **controller.test.ts**

```
import request from 'supertest';
import App from '../../app';
import Controller from '../controller';

....
....
describe('run test', () => {
    let app: App;
    let controller: Controller;

    beforeAll(() => {
        let tenant = "Sample Tenant";
        controller = new Controller();
        app = new App(tenant, [controller]);
    });
      describe('Check Decision', () => {

        const samplePayload = {
            "payload":{.....}
        };
        it("checking opa for accepted permission", async () => {
            const res = await request(app.getServer())
                .post(`/decision`).send(samplePayload);
            
            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
            expect(res.body).toHaveProperty("decision_id");
            expect(res.body).toHaveProperty("result");
            expect(res.body).toHaveProperty("result.allow", true);
        })

})
```

For the above I want to force the response to have the specified properties in the body and have a status of 200. I have tried the following by declaring at the top level, but have been unsuccessful

```
jest.mock('../../middleware/decision.middleware', () => {
  jest.fn((req, res, next) => {
    req.body = {
      "decision_id": "580ae1ff-f335-4382-8207-f5094aba59b9",
      "result":{
        "allow": true
      }
    }
    next();
  })
})
```

Comment: If you're writing an integration-level test, rather than mock out parts of the app you could provide the appropriate response at the transport layer using [`msw`](https://mswjs.io/) or [`nock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock).

Comment: @jonrsharpe do you have example of this with jest or if you could provide a snippet of this for `nock`.

Comment: I've used `nock` [here](https://github.com/textbook/trello-done/blob/master/src/__tests__/integration.test.js?ts=2) and `msw` [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/9b511011e4a576f85469c2cd4f71ab47261a880b/client/src/pages/Home.test.js?ts=2), both with Jest. You can also look at their docs to see how to set it up.